# ¿Dar estilo a diferentes paginas de un documento pdf, usando fpdf y fpdi?

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

Estoy usando Fpdi y fpdf.
par agregar texto  al documento pdf, aparte de eso también estoy uniendo documentos pdf en uno solo.

para ellos estoy usando un método que ofrece la documentación de fpdi:

ejemplo simple agregando texto:
https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/demos/simple-demo/

ejemplo concatenando/adjuntando documentos pdf.
https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/demos/concatenate-fake/

estoy en la parte donde estoy concatenando/adjuntando documentos pdf en uno solo.

pero necesito agregar estilo o texto a cada uno, no sé hacer referencia a cada hoja del documento para agregar el  texto que necesito.

mi código php:

```
<?php
use \setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;
require_once 'librerias/fpdf/fpdf.php';
require_once 'librerias/fpdi/src/autoload.php';

//clase para adjuntar documentos pdf
class ConcatPdf extends Fpdi
{
    public $files = array();

    public function setFiles($files)
    {
        $this->files = $files;
    }

    public function concat()
    {
        foreach($this->files AS $file) {
            $pageCount = $this->setSourceFile($file);
            for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++) {
                $pageId = $this->ImportPage($pageNo);
                $s = $this->getTemplatesize($pageId);
                $this->AddPage($s['orientation'], $s);
                $this->useImportedPage($pageId);
            }
            
        }
    }
}


$url=__DIR__ .'/documents/CERTIFICADO-V1SMRef.pdf';
$pdf = new ConcatPdf();

$pdf->setFiles(array($url, $url, $url));
$pdf->concat();

date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
$dateActu=date('d-m-Y h:i:s A');

$pdf->Output('I','--name_formato_calidad.pdf');  //visualiza
```

este es el código que tengo agregando el texto pero en un solo documento necesito hacer algo similar pero con el código de arriba:

```
<?php

// iniciar FPDI
$pdf = new FPDI();

// agregar una página
$pdf->addPage();

// establece el archivo fuente
 $pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile(__DIR__ .'/documents/CERTIFICADO-V1SMRef.pdf');

 // importar la página 1
$tplidx = $pdf->importPage(1, '/MediaBox');
// usa la página importada y colócala en la posición 10,10 con un ancho de 100 mm
$pdf->useTemplate($tplidx, 10, 10, 200);


// ahora escribe algo de texto encima de la página importada
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
$pdf->SetTextColor(255,0,0); 
$pdf->SetXY(10, 0); 



date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
$dateActu=date('d-m-Y h:i:s A');

$pdf->Write(10,$dateActu." PAGINA: 1-1"); //colocando texto en el documento

$pdf->Output('I', $dateActu.'--name_formato_calidad.pdf');  //visualiza
```